# An error while file compilation

Tags: android, linux

I'm trying to compile .c file using following command:

```
arm-linux-androideabi-gcc -shared -o test.so test.c -I /home/sss/Desktop/ssl/include/ -I /home/sss/Desktop/android-ndk-r10e/platforms/android-21/arch-arm/usr/include/ -llog
```

But I get this error
`/usr/lib/gcc/arm-linux-androideabi/4.7.3/../../../../arm-linux-androideabi/bin/ld: error: cannot find -llog
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status`

So, does anyone know what's this?

Comment: Having a -I (to setup the include path, i.e. where to find the .h files to use during compilation) but not having a -L (to setup the library path for the .a/.so/etc. libraries that the .h define) is a red flag... should you be doing something like -L/home/sss/Desktop/android-ndk-r10e/platforms/android-21/arch-arm/usr/lib ?

Comment: @Foon,
Sorry, I've tried
arm-linux-androideabi-gcc -shared -o test.so test.c -I/home/sss/Desktop/ssl/include/ -L//home/sss/Desktop/ssl/include/ -I/home/sss/Desktop/android-ndk-r10e/platforms/android-21/arch-arm/usr/include/ -L/home/sss/Desktop/android-ndk-r10e/platforms/android-21/arch-arm/usr/include/  -llog
Same result

Comment: @Foon, do you know what -llog is?

Comment: Note that I said  -L/home/sss/Desktop/android-ndk-r10e/platforms/android-21/arch-arm/usr/lib (to be clear  -L<snip>/lib vs -L <snip>/include.  I haven't touched c-based android dev recently enough to remember what -llog is, except as much as the convention for Unix is that if you have a library file called liblog.a, you do -llog ... so I'd suggest doing find /home/sss/Desktop -name "liblog.*" and putting -L to point to the directory that contains this...